# Setting up sessions in an Electron App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, session, electron

Okay, so I'm very, very new to sessions and am trying to implement a login/logout user system in an Electron app.

I have an SQLite database and right now I am passing the username and password through an Angular controller function, to another JavaScript file which handles the database transaction (and checking the hash and all that bcrypt jazz). That function then returns the necessary variables back to the Angular controller.

I've been trying a couple different solutions that I've found online with `express-session`, but I've got to be honest, there are a few things I'm just not getting and nothing seems to work correctly. So I've just got a couple questions on setting up the thing.

(1) Where do I create the session? In the Angular `controllers.js` function? Or in the database transaction function? (Or somewhere else entirely?). [When I say creating the function, I mean this:

```
var app = express()
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))
```

(2) Once the session is created, do I pass it somewhere to make the variables accessible in the Angular `controllers.js`?

(3) How do I access these variables once I've passed them? So the code shown is usually something along the lines of:

```
// Use the session middleware
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))

// Access the session as req.session
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.views) {
    req.session.views++
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.write('<p>views: ' + req.session.views + '</p>')
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (req.session.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>')
    res.end()
  } else {
    req.session.views = 1
    res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
  }
})
```

But how do I assign, say `req.session.username = "Blahblahblah'` and then print it to the console?

Apologies for the questions, I really think I'm just missing some sort of step here and am not quite sure how to solve it.

(Code is from https://github.com/expressjs/session, although I've also tried the guide here: https://stormpath.com/blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-node-dot-js-sessions)